# How to add spaces between each row in dataTable

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How do I add some spaces between each row of the table. I try this

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="yourTableClass">
    <p:column style="background-color: ##EFF2F9">
         //Content here
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

but it does not work

I used primefaces 2.2.1
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, check your browser make/version: `border-spacing` is [not supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html) on IE6/7. Secondly, the `border-spacing` only works when the `border-collapse` of the table is set to `separate`. Likely some PrimeFaces specific stylesheet has set it to `collapse` (which is the general UI preferred form of border representation). This way the `border-spacing` won't work.

Thus, all with all this should work, including the IE6/7 hack on the last declaration:

```
.yourTableClass { 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 10px; 
    *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px');
}
```

with

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="yourTableClass">
```

*(favour classes over inline styles)*

---

**Update**: as per the screenshot and the comments, PrimeFaces wraps the generated HTML `<table>` inside a `<div>` and applies the `style`/`styleClass` on it instead of on the wrapped `<table>`. I did not expect that. In such case, you need the following CSS declaration instead:

```
.yourTableClass table { 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 10px; 
    *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '10px');
}
```

Comment: still cant seems to get it working. So I did exactly what you show above. Still nothing change. So when I use firebug to look at the style, the attribute `border-collapse: separate;` get cross out. And I inherit `border-collapse: collapse` from `.ui-datatable table`. I post a screenshot of my firebug style in my original code, please take a look, BalusC

Comment: Ensure that this style is definied as last style in the HTML DOM tree ordering. If the PF style appears after your style, then it will get precedence. **Edit:** oh this is embarrassing, I checked the screenshot, PF wraps the table within a `<div>` and applies the class on it. Try `.yourTableClass table {}` instead.

Comment: yup, that does it. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

not really sure about primefaces, so am not familiar with which attributes can be used on what bits..

but `border-spacing` can't really be reliably used yet as a style.. tables still really need the "old fashioned" `cellspacing` attribute

does `<p:dataTable cellspacing="10">` work?

### updated as per new information

change the rule

```
.yourTableClass {}
```

to

```
div div.yourTableClass table {}
```

if your `layout.css` gets called before `skin.css` this should make the rule still override it

and you will need the IE hack as mentioned above and maybe you'll need to make it as specific too

Comment: p:dataTable does not have attribute `cellspacing`, I use PF 2.2.1 btw

Comment: ah Ok sorry just when you said you had tried border-spacing I presumed a table, maybe the actual rows are not really table rows  - `tr`'s - have you tried just adding `style="margin: 10px 0;"` to see if that does anything, I take it does accept the style attribute as that's what you used in your example

Comment: btw, I did try to access the primefaces site to see if I could find out more, but it's timimg out for me

Comment: @clairesuzy: I think the showcase is temporary down. Seems like they are migrating the showcase to PF3.0 M1. Give it couple hours, it should be back online

Comment: @Harry Pham, I see you're now fixed so no worries.. I also updated my answer with specific style rule info, before I saw @BalusC had already helped you .. but glad you got it sorted, BalusC got my upvote anyway ;)